# emsdk activate - No tools/SDKs specified to activate?

Tags: webassembly

WASM and Python have been installed (following tutorial). "emsdk install latest " was completed.  "Environment Variables > System Variables > Path > New" has been set.

When I go to a directory I enter "emsdk activate" I see "No tools/SDKs specified to activate".  What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to enter "emsdk activate latest" first.